# Displaying route with pushpoints on wp8

Tags: c#, google-maps, windows-phone-8, here-api

I have mapped tour on google maps, same thing I can get on bing maps to, how can I draw the same route in my WP8 application via internet connection?
[Tour](https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msid=217419086831970217022.0004b80b1823ac8969850&msa=0&ll=41.963575,43.665848&spn=0.368119,0.727158)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download the belonging KML file from Google Maps. There is a link on the route panel.
2. Write a XML parser to interpret the coordinates in the KML file.
3. Read the [Guide to the Windows Phone 8 Maps API](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Lumia/maps-and-navigation/guide-to-the-wp8-maps-api.html) on how to display a route.